# Save repeated calculations in Python Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

In Pandas, I can use .apply to apply functions to two columns. For example,

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A':['a', 'a', 'a', 'b'], 'B':[3, 3, 2, 5], 'C':[2, 2, 2, 8]})
formula = lambda x: (x.B + x.C)**2
df.apply(formula, axis=1)
```

But, notice that results on the first two rows are the same since all the inputs are the same. In large dataset with complicated operations. These repeated calculations is likely to slow down my program. Is there a way that I can program it so that I can save time with these repeated calculations?

Comment: One comment: for simple operations like this, it will be much faster on large arrays to use broadcasting rather than ``apply``: for example ``result = (df.B + df.C) ** 2``

Comment: understood. I'm more thinking of operations such as calling geopy's distance function.

Answer (score 6):

You can use a technique called  [memoization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memoization). For functions which accept hashable arguments, you can use the built-in `functools.lru_cache`.

```
from functools import lru_cache

@lru_cache(maxsize=None)
def cached_function(B, C):
    return (B + C)**2

def formula(x):
    return cached_function(x.B, x.C)
```

Notice that I had to pass the values through to the cached function for `lru_cache` to work correctly because Series objects aren't hashable.

Comment: Thank you. In trying these code, I get TypeError: ("'Series' objects are mutable, thus they cannot be hashed", 'occurred at index 0'). Am I missing something?

Comment: [Series objects are mutable, thus they cannot be hashed error calling to_csv](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32568012/series-objects-are-mutable-thus-they-cannot-be-hashed-error-calling-to-csv)

Answer (score 1):

You could use [`np.unique`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.unique.html) to create a copy of the dataframe consisting of only the unique rows, then do the calculation on those, and construct the full results.

For example:

```
import numpy as np

# convert to records for use with numpy
rec = df.to_records(index=False)
arr, ind = np.unique(rec, return_inverse=True)

# find dataframe of unique rows
df_small = pd.DataFrame(arr)

# Apply the formula & construct the full result
df_small.apply(formula, axis=1).iloc[ind].reset_index()
```

Even faster than using `apply` here would be to use broadcasting: for example, simply compute

```
(df.B + df.C) ** 2
```

If this is still too slow, you can use this method on the de-duplicated dataframe, as above.